Does this aliquot-fibonacci combination ever end? How many distinct sequences are there?
Recently, I've been messing around with a sort of aliquot sequence meets Fibonacci sequence. For example, start with the numbers $3$ and $4$. The aliquot sum of $3$ is $1$, and the aliquot sum of $4$ is $3$. The next number in our sequence is therefore $1+3=4$. Continuing, we find the next number in our sequence is $3 + 3 = 6$, followed by $3 + 6 = 9$, and so on. Here are the first twenty terms of the sequence:
$$3, 4, 4, 6, 9, 10, 12, 24, 52, 82, 90, 188, 292, 374, 500, 866, 1028, 1214, 1388, 1658, 1880, 3272...$$
The sequence seems likely to go on forever, and it's not the only one. Here's the first twenty terms of the sequence beginning with $4$ and $8$:
$$4, 8, 10, 15, 17, 10, 9, 12, 20, 38, 44, 62, 74, 74, 80, 146, 182, 230, 356, 476, 806, 1070...$$
Interestingly, this sequence seems to grow much slower than the previous one. However, not all sequences appear to grow forever; many end in a $2, 2, 2, 2...$ loop, such as the sequence beginning with $6$ and $8$:
$$6, 8, 13, 8, 8, 14, 17, 11, 2, 2, 2...$$
It appears that there are many distinct ever-growing sequences. The one starting with $6$ and $6$ grows startlingly fast:
$$6, 6, 12, 22, 30, 56, 106, 120, 296, 514, 534, 806, 1084, 1358, 1814, 1904, 3470, 5354, 5474, 7574, 10328, 14486$$
Note that the $6,6$ sequence and the $4,8$ sequence share the term $806$, however not one but two terms are enough to determine the rest of the sequence, and so the sequences go their separate ways.
My main question is:

Do these sequences go on forever (without periodicity)?

It seems very likely that they do (with the use of computers, we see that they continue increasing far into the trillions), but there is always a possibility that they reach a square number, which would make the next number in the sequence odd. After this happens, it seems like the sequence tends to trend downwards, like so:
$$3000, 4096, 10455, 11784, 25425, 38253, 34680, 90003, 112237, 36398, 18203, 18479, 1382, 1799, 959, 410, 491, 347, 2, 2...$$
So the question remains: can we prove that these sequences grow forever?
As an aside, if we prove the main question:

Are there finitely or infinitely many distinct endless aperiodic sequences? If the former, how many?

Any insight is appreciated!

Here is some context on aliquot sequences (might be useful).
